# Non-static class function - pointer

Tags: c++, указатели

В ранних версиях **Android NDK** использовался **gnustl**.

У меня есть класс *Player*, в нём не статичная функция `float getSpeed();`. Используя **gnustl** я мог получить ссылку на эту функцию: `&Player:getSpeed`. После обновления **NDK** (и добавление `libc++`), данная возможность пропала. Появилась ошибка: `cannot cast from type float (Player::*) to pointer type void*`.

Есть варианты решения?

Comment: @Abyx, это используется вместе с Substrate, поэтому данный способ был очень быстрым и удобным. Возможно есть другие пути использования?

Comment: UPD: Амперсанд использовался вместо dlsym. Не мог точно выразить мысль, но прочитав про ф-ию - могу: с помощью амперсанда я получал адрес символа этой функции, чтобы отловить. Я создаю мод и использование dlsym напрямую затрачивает много времени, через амперсанд всё получалось в разы быстрее и эффективнее.

Comment: @Abyx, ссылка на символ получалось. Уже всё решил.